# Do I need a visa to enter South Korea while traveling to India from Australia?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, south-korea

I am an Indian national, living and working in Australia for a year. I’m on a bridging visa here. Now I’m going to India and my flight from Sydney is transiting through Seoul airport. It has a layover of more than 20 hours. Can I go out of the airport transit area?

Comment: The answer of the above question may apply to your situation.